# Does this CouchDB error look familiar?

Tags: couchdb

My build server is giving me an error that doesn't show up on my local instance. It boils down to the following. I can submit a form to the couchdb server using the following command and it will get passed to an update handler.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/master_build/_design/couchforms/_update/xform -d @meta.xml
```

When I try the same thing on the build server, I get the following:

```
{"error":"normal","reason":"..."}
```

Where "..." is the escaped version of the following:

```
{gen_server,call,
            [couch_query_servers,
             {ret_proc,{proc,<0.22251.7>,<<"javascript">>,
                             {couch_os_process,prompt},
                             {couch_os_process,set_timeout},
                             {couch_os_process,stop}}}]}
```

Other simple queries to the couchdb server on the build server respond normally.

What does this message mean?

Comment: It looks like you haven't pasted the entire text of the traceback. Without more context its hard to pin down exactly what it was doing. Though off the top of my head it looks like you're update handler had an unexpected error. To rule out the possibility of your code, try the simplest _update handler you can think of to see if its particular to that request or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question here. I was getting this error because

```
sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

on Ubuntu installs a very out of date version, while I had the latest version on my own computer. To install couch on Ubuntu, it's probably easiest to download an up-to-date binary at http://www.couch.io/get . At least as of now, it's probably *not* a good idea to install the apt-get version.